# Finding Difference Between Strings in Two Dataframes/Lists, Output Difference

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I have an excel sheet and I am trying to analyse the difference between two versions.
Specifically, I have two columns; A and B. 
I imported into python and using pandas I made both A and B their own dataframes (respectively called dfA and dfB). Here they have the following:

`key   dfA          dfB
 1     cat         bigcat
 2     dog         smalldog
 3     mouse       hugemouse
 4     child       normalchild`

I am trying to output a third column containing the string difference between the two dataframes, so essentially a third dataframe/column:

```
ABdifference
big
small
huge
normal
```

I've looked into using the difflib library however I don't think it'll produce the results in a readable format

I'll paste the code of what I have so far, but it's really not much as I haven't coded in some time and I thought it'd be easier than I thought...

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import difflib

df = pd.read_excel('somesheet.xlsx', sheet_name='Diff')

first= df['A']
second = df['B']
```

i'm not married to the idea of using pandas and dataframes, i just assumed it was the best way to go about excel data.

If anyone could assist in anyway it would be hugely appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: You should post the rest of the columns as well, we can check if there are `keycolumns` which we can use to simply combine the data.

Comment: can't really post the raw data as it's sensitive (and spans 8000 rows and 40 columns) but i'll add an arbitrary key to my post

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dataframe.apply` with a `lambda` function:

```
print(dfA, '\n')
print(dfB)

    col1
0    cat
1    dog
2  mouse
3  child 

          col2
0       bigcat
1     smalldog
2    hugemouse
3  normalchild
```

Combine the dataframe with `pd.concat`:

```
df_combined = pd.concat([dfA, dfB], axis=1)
print(df_combined)
    col1         col2
0    cat       bigcat
1    dog     smalldog
2  mouse    hugemouse
3  child  normalchild
```

Use `.apply` with `replace`

```
df_combined['col'] = df_combined.apply(lambda x: x['col2'].replace(x['col1'], ''), axis=1)

print(df_combined)
    col1         col2     col
0    cat       bigcat     big
1    dog     smalldog   small
2  mouse    hugemouse    huge
3  child  normalchild  normal
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply!

unfortunately, i'm getting a TypeError when applying the lambda function:
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.


The debug menu points to `df_combined['col'] = df_combined.apply(lambda x: x['col2'].replace(x['col1'], ''), axis=1)` as the source of the error..

As for a key, I do have keys associated with both versions that i'm comparing. I'll update my original post

Comment: Is one of the columns you try to replace with an `integer`? For example is your `col1` an integer? @DannyMoncadea

Comment: No, they're not integers they're all strings. In fact I tried it once with my data set and once again with the sample data i posted and it brought up the same error

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below formula:

```
=IF(FIND(A2,B2)>1,LEFT(B2,FIND(A2,B2)-1),IF(FIND(B2,B2)=1,RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-LEN(A2))))
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't seem to work :( 
so my data set isn't strictly a string with added characters at the end, and this function doesn't seem to account for that and only looks at length from the end